# R - Mean values of numbers in a sequence in a dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean of values in a column (y) that are being sequentially counted (1, 2, 3, etc.) within another column (x). An example dataframe is shown below.

```
> df
   x  y
1  1 15
2  2 20
3  4 16
4  5 12
5  6 17
6  8 14
7  9 13
8 10 19
```

I would like to get a vector result that will read out the mean values of numbers in a numerical sequence. The desired vector would read: 17.5 15 15.33333

I am not sure the best way to produce this desired result, but I have tried and failed to make a for loop using `diff(df[,1])` to find the breakpoints.

Any help anyone could provide would be appreciated. This is a small example dataset, but the goal is to apply it to a large dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a grouping column from the `diff` using `cumsum` on a logical vector

```
with(df, tapply(y, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) != 1)), FUN = mean))
```

-output

```
  1        2        3 
17.50000 15.00000 15.33333
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L), y = c(15L, 
20L, 16L, 12L, 17L, 14L, 13L, 19L)), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: `with(df, tapply(y, x-seq(x), mean))` would also work great

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** code reduced 2 lines:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id_Group =cumsum(x-lag(x, default = x[1])>=2)) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(y, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  pull(mean)
```

Here is a `dplyr` version:

1. calculate the difference between the lagged `x`
2. create group with `cumsum(diff>=2)`
3. calculate mean and `pull` the vector.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(diff= x-lag(x, default = x[1])) %>% 
  group_by(id_Group =cumsum(diff>=2)) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(y, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  pull(mean)
```

```
[1] 17.50000 15.00000 15.33333
```